# Copy current word that cursor is in

Tags: appcode

If my cursor is, for example, like `some_w|ord`. How could I move the text `some_word` into my paste buffer?

Right now, I execute the follows commands (OSX 10.5+ keymap),

⌥-Left arrow: Go to beginning of word

⌥-Shift-Right arrow: Highlight to end of word

⌘-C: Copy highlighted text

Right now, this is three keystrokes. Is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Try `⌥-Arrow Up` and `⌘-C` after

With Idea Keymap it is `⌘-W` and `⌘-C`